# printing the properties of Tomcat DBCP DataSource object

Tags: java, debugging, tomcat, apache-commons-dbcp

How to print the DBCP configuration of a `DataSource` returned by `tomcat DBCP framework`?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the getter methods for looking inside a `DataSource` object.

> OR

You can simply use the `toString()` method of `DataSource` object which will print the pool properties